# jsf spring security login error message

Tags: jsf, authentication, spring-security, message

I'm using spring security 3 in my jsf2 web app.

How can I show a bad credential message in my login form without appending a get param ?login_error to the authenticated-fail-login-page?

I've tried using a phase listener like this tutorial says:

http://tutorials.slackspace.de/tutorial/Custom-login-page-with-JSF-and-Spring-Security-3

But it doesn't work.

Neither with a preRenderView listener.

And neither checking the spring security last exception for rendering the message.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

My login page:

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="error" value="#{autenticacionController.error}" />
<f:event listener="#{autenticacionController.comprobarAuthException}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
<h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
<h:form id="formLogin" prependId="false">
<h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Usuario:" />
<h:inputText id="j_username" value="#{autenticacionController.administrador.login}" />
<h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Contraseña:" />
<h:inputSecret id="j_password" value="#{autenticacionController.administrador.password}" />
<h:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{autenticacionController.loginAction}" />
<h:commandButton value="Cancelar" immediate="true" action="#{autenticacionController.cancelarAction}" />
</h:form>
```

My managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="autenticacionController")
@RequestScoped
public class AutenticacionController extends BaseController {

    //entidad "administrador" contra el que validar los campos del form login
    private Administrador administrador = new Administrador();

    //propiedad de spring-security (true si el usuario no es anónimo)
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean autenticado;

    //propiedad para guardar el param GET si hubo fallo en la autenticación de SS
    private int error;

    //Constructor vacío del Backing Bean controlador
    public AutenticacionController() {
        log.info("Creación del backing bean AutenticacionController");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //inicializar atributos del backing bean
        log.info("PostConstruct del backing bean BarcoController");
    }


    //Getters y setters de atributos del backing bean
    public Administrador getAdministrador() {
        return administrador;
    }
    public void setAdministrador(Administrador administrador) {
        this.administrador = administrador;
    }

    public boolean isAutenticado() {
        Authentication autenticacion = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        boolean resultado = (autenticacion != null) &&
                            !(autenticacion instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) &&
                            autenticacion.isAuthenticated();
        return resultado;
    }

    public int getError() {
        return error;
    }
    public void setError(int error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    //MÉTODO LISTENER del evento preRenderView en la página login.
    //Para comprobar si la autenticación de Spring Security falló (error=1).
    //En ese caso muestra el error con un faces message.
    public void comprobarAuthException (ComponentSystemEvent event){
        log.info("listener comprobarAuth");
        if (error==1) {
            String msj = "";
            Exception e = (Exception) UtilJsf.getParamSessionMap(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
            log.info("SSexception = "+((e==null)?"null":e.getMessage()));
            if (e != null) {
                String ultimoUsuario = (String) UtilJsf.getParamSessionMap(WebAttributes.LAST_USERNAME);
                log.info("SS last_username = "+ultimoUsuario);
                administrador.setLogin(ultimoUsuario);
                if (e instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
                    msj = UtilJsf.getMsjProperties("msjsInfo", "UsuPwdIncorrectos");
                } else {
                    msj = UtilJsf.getMsjProperties("msjsInfo", "ErrorAutenticacion");
                }
                UtilJsf.mostrarFacesMsjGlobal(msj);
            }
        }
        return;
    }


    /* ******************************* */
    /* Métodos "action" del form login */
    /* ******************************* */

    // EVENTO: Pulsar el botón "entrar" del form login
    // Reenviar(FORWARD) la petición a la URL "/j_spring_security_check" para autenticarse
    // También se debe configurar el filtro de spring-security para que procese forwards
    public void loginAction () {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/j_spring_security_check");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    // EVENTO: Pulsar el boton "cancelar" en el form login
    // No hacer nada --> Ir a la pantalla de inicio de la aplic
    public String cancelarAction () {
        return "/inicio";
    }

}
```

In my configuration of Spring Security I have:

```
authentication-failure-url="/faces/paginas/autenticacion/login.xhtml?error=1"
```

If I remove the error param, and the viewParam from the login page, and in the listener I just check for the Spring Security exception, it doesn't work.

Thanks for the logout, my approach for it is similar, I have the following link for it:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout" rendered="#{autenticacionController.autenticado}">Cerrar sesión (Administrador)</h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use an `<f:event>` on preRenderView that will update the messages component on my form.  This is how I did it.

```
<f:event listener="#{loginBean.updateMessages(true)}" type="preRenderView" />
        <div style="margin-left: 50px; width: 500px;"><br />
        <h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false">

            <p:messages id="errorMessages" />
            <label for="j_username">
                <h:outputText value="Username:" /><br />
            </label>
            <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" width="500" style="width: 300px;" />

            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="j_password">
                <h:outputText value="Password:" /><br />
            </label>
            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" width="500" style="width: 300px;" />
            &nbsp;<h:link value="Forgot my password" outcome="forgotpassword" /> 
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="_spring_security_remember_me">
                <h:outputText value="Remember me" />
            </label>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="_spring_security_remember_me" />
            <br /><br />
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" type="submit" id="login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" value="Login" update="errorMessages" />
        </h:form>
        </div>
```

And then in my LoginBean managed bean, I forward the request onto the Spring Security servlet as so, and update the messages.  You will notice that I also have code for a logout action if you are interested in seeing how I approached that problem as well.

```
private String username;
private String password;    

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(final String username) {
    this.username = username.trim();
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(final String password) {
    this.password = password.trim();
}

public void updateMessages(boolean update) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Start LoginBean.updateMessages");
    ex = (Exception)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
        .get(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

if (ex != null) {
    log.error("Authentication Failed! ", ex);
    System.err.println("Authentication Failed! " + ex.getMessage());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex.getMessage()));
}
    System.out.println("End LoginBean.updateMessages");
}

public String doLogin() {
    log.info("Start LoginBean.doLogin");
    try {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                 .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception doLogin", e);
    } finally {
        log.info("End LoginBean.doLogin");
    }
return "";
}

public String logout() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    if (!sessionMap.containsKey("sessionBean"))
        return "";

    SessionBean sessionBean = (SessionBean)sessionMap.get("sessionBean");
    log.info("Logging out user: " + sessionBean.getLoggedInUser().getUsername());

    sessionMap.remove("sessionBean");

    //HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    //session.invalidate();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest())
        .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_logout");

try {
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest(),
               (ServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        log.error("ServletException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IOException", e);
    }

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
// It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.

log.info("End LoginBean.logout");       
return "";
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    return sessionMap.containsKey("sessionBean");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think I better understand your problem now.  I remember that I had trouble getting this to work too, so basically I had to write my own class that implements `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and properly implement the method:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {
  //Do business logic stuff, logging, etc...
  request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, ex);
  response.sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
```

Basically you see that I am instantiating an exception and setting it as a session attribute so that later in my managed bean it can be retrieved and converted into a `FacesMessage`.

You will also have to declare this `AuthenticationFailureHandler` as a custom handler for authentication failure events in your Spring Security configuration file *(Note that I am also showing that I do the same thing for an authentication success handler, but you may or may not want to do that as well)*.

```
<form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessBean"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureBean"  />

...
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureBean" class="com.maple.controllers.FailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="userBo" ref="userController" /> <!-- Just injecting my BL layer... -->
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My approach is similar to yours, but if I don't add the ?error param to the authenticated-fail-login-page, it doesn't work. I use a preRenderView listener but in the method I check for the error param. If I don't use that param and just check for the spring security exception, it doesn't work. I edit my question to add my code so that you can see. Sorry if my english isn't very good, but I'm from Spain.

Comment: @choquero70 I updated my answer with more details... Let me know if you understand.

Comment: Thank you maple_shaft. I think that I understand more or less what you are saying, but I have to check it. Although I don't understand why it is necessary to put the Spring Security exception as a session attribute in your onAuthenticationFailure method (Spring Security is supossed to do that, but surprisingly it is null when I check it in the preRenderView listener).

Comment: Thank you @maple_shaft. I think your solutions works, but finally I decided to use the url param.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a spring bean that implements AuthenticationFailureHandler

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute("message", exception.getMessage());
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/login.xhtml");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

then configure spring security to use it :

```
@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;
...
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error=true")
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
...
```

finally, in login.xhtml, use this code to show the message (if you don't use primefaces, just adapt the code for your context) :

```
<p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty request.getAttribute('message')}" class="ui-messages ui-widget" >
         <div class="ui-messages-error ui-corner-all">
                 <span class="ui-messages-error-icon">
                 </span>
                 <ul>
                    <li role="alert" aria-atomic="true">
                         <span class="ui-messages-error-summary">#{request.getAttribute('message')}</span>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
          </div>
  </p:outputPanel>
```